# Selecting from an inner query a second time

Tags: mysql, sql

While practicing writing SQL queries, I noticed that I'm not able to execute queries in a form similar to this:

(1)

```
SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM
   (SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM ...) AS table     
WHERE attr1 >= ALL
   (SELECT attr1 FROM table)
```

The idea in (1) is that I am selecting from an inner query with the alias 'table'. I also want to add a WHERE clause to apply comparisons and obtain my desired query result. So I compare the attribute to attributes from 'table'.

In this specific case, I'm selecting all the attr1's that obtain the max value in the inner query result assigned the alias 'tables'.

However the above example doesn't work and I get an error.

I realise that If I do something like below, I'll obtain a query result:

(2)

```
SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM
   (SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM ...) AS alias1   
WHERE attr1 >= ALL
   (SELECT attr1 FROM ...)
```

where the two inner queries are the same, except for the fact that attr2 is not present in the second one.

My only issue with query (2) is that if the inner query is quite long, then you're essentially copying and pasting a big chunk of code to be reused again under the WHERE clause.

My question is why query (1) is not valid and if there are any better alternatives to query (2).

Comment: If the `WHERE` should work on the inner query, then try to add it to the inner not the outer query.

Comment: Your second query makes no sense.  You have an alias in the `where` clause.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement are all really helpful.

Comment: That's my mistake, I didn't mean to place an alias in the ```where``` clause. Will fix it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only one row, then you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT attr1, attr2
FROM (SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM ...) t
ORDER BY attr1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, you can use `RANK()` to get duplicates:

```
SELECT attr1, attr2
FROM (SELECT attr1, attr2,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY attr1 DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ...
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

In earlier versions, you either need to repeat the subquery or using variables.

Answer (score 0):

The query 1 is not valid  becuase the SELECT clause and the column build dinamically using subquery a performed  after  the FROM and WHERE clasue

so the table  is not available at the moment you execute the select .

the second, should not be valid for the presence of an alias in a where column,   a part fo this

```
   SELECT attr1, attr2 
FROM
   (SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM ...) AS alias1   
WHERE attr1 >= ALL
   (SELECT attr1 FROM ...)
```

is valid  because  there is not alias in the subquery select clause

but  looking to your code  you should eval  if instead of suqbery for select and where condition you can refactor you query as  a joined  query

```
SELECT attr1, attr2 
FROM your_table 
(
  SELECT attr1, attr2 
  FROM your_table 
  WHERE  .... ) AS alias1   
WHERE alias1.attr1   >= your_table.att1
```